# Remove Cloned Event JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am adding events in a fieldset and while I can add them, I am unsure how to write the correct function to remove them. I had it working in javascript but was asked to write it using JQuery and cannot seem to make it work. All example I have researched don't seem to work with my original cloning function which builds a remove button in it. The fieldsets also duplicate and I have the code working for that already, just need a little help with this remove event function.

Here it the javascript/jquery:

```
var _eventCounter = 0;
var removeEventButton = $("<input></input>").attr("type", "button").attr("value", "-");
function addEvent(num)
{
    _eventCounter++;
    var c = $("#event-code-"+num).clone(true);
    c.attr("id", "event-code-"+num);
    var eventName = "s"+num+"_e["+_eventCounter+"]";
    $('#'+ eventName, c).val('')
    $("#textNumberRequired1", c).val('');
    removeEventButton.attr("onClick", "removeEvent('+c+')");
    $(c).append(removeEventButton.clone(true));
    $("#event-placeholder-"+num).append(c);

}

function removeEvent(c) {
    //$("#event-placeholder #event-code-1").remove(); 
    $(c).remove(); 

}
```

Here is the html/php:

```
<div id="section_placeholder">
    <div id="section_template1">
        <fieldset class="box-outline-blue">
            <legend>Section Requirements</legend>
            <h3>Number of events required:  </h3><input type="text" id="textNumberRequired1" size="8" name="numberRequired1"><br>
            <br />
            <h3>Please enter the required event codes: </h3>
            <div id="event-placeholder-1">
                <div class="eventCode" id="event-code-1">   
                    <br />Event Code: <input type="text" id = "eventCodes_section1" name="s1_e[]" size=8 > <input type="button" id="add" onClick="addEvent(1)" value="+">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br /><br />

        </fieldset>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery.off() is your friend : https://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change the remove button onclick to jQuery:

  this: `removeEventButton.attr("onclick", "removeEvent("+c+")");`

  to: `$(removeEventButton).on("click", removeEvent);`
- Add a `class` to your `event-placeholder-x div`, it will be easier to delete

  `<div id="event-placeholder-1" class='placeholder'>`
- And finally, when the `remove button` receives a click your `removeEvent` should find it's parent and then remove it

  this: `$(c).remove();`

  to: `$(this).parentsUntil('.placeholder').remove();`